# Importing csv to mysql and an array value to first column of table

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I want to insert my array value `result =['2018-10-18_trx_result-reuslt.csv']` to my column `date_sourced`, but my problem is how can I include this to my query for rows in my csv data.

**Here is my code to import my csv to mysql table**

for now, my `date_sourced` is `0000-00-00`, so I want to replace it by my `result` variable

```
import csv
import mysql.connector
import re

result =['2018-10-18_trx_result-reuslt.csv']
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='jeremy_db')
file = open('C:\\Users\\trendMICRO\\Desktop\\OJT\\test.csv', 'rb')  
csv_data = csv.reader(file)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(date_sourced, sha1, vsdt,trendx,notes )' 'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s,%s)',row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

**You can do:**

> `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'filename' INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test`

Answer (score 1):

Because [allow_local_infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) is `True` you can use [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)`'filename' INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test` to easily load CSV files.